# Rest API response 404 Not found when run project with Java Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have app with spring boot, i want to run this app with `Java Application` but when i call rest API it always response 404, but with `Tomcat server` it's ok. I don't know why

Here is my main app

```
package com.secret;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SecretApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecretApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

here is my file pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.secret</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySecret</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my controller

```
package com.secret.demo;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.secret.common.dto.ResponseBodyDto;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class Demo {

    @GetMapping(value = "/user")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getUserByUsername() throws Exception{

        ResponseBodyDto<Object> dto = new ResponseBodyDto<>();
        dto.setData("Ok");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And When i run my app by `Java Application` always get 404 when call rest API http://localhost:8080/MySecret/demo/user

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-28T08:03:05.090+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/MySecret/demo/user"
}
```

But when i run my app by `Tomcat Server` then it still success

```
{
    "code": "R_200",
    "message": "Your request has been processed successfully.",
    "totalRecord": 0,
    "data": "Ok"
}
```

I don't want to use `Tomcat Server` to run my app anymore, Someone help me pls!!!

Comment: When you run your application as java app, try to do a request to http://localhost:8080/demo/user , not to http://localhost:8080/MySecret/demo/user

Comment: Omg thanks alot @Geotodac, it's really resolve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your project as jar (java application), you should use localhost:8080/demo/user

When you run your application into a server (jboss per example) the name of your war file is the root path.

localhost:8080/MySecret/demo/user

I think your war file is MySecret.war.

That's the reason of the difference between the first and the second. Since you don't have a base path, /demo/user is the path of your endpoint.